# Unable to send requests to backend API within NextAuth authorize function using credentials provider in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, next-auth

I am using NextAuth.js version 4 and have set up a custom authorize function using the CredentialsProvider to handle login. The API endpoint for login is working correctly, but when I attempt to make a request to the backend API server within the authorize function, it doesn't seem to reach the API, and instead, I receive an error. I have provided the code for the route.ts file where the NextAuth configuration is set up.

**I tried this:**
in route.js file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log(credentials);
        try {
          const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/auth/login/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ...credentials }),
          });
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("Incorrect credentials");
          }
          const data = await res.json();
          const user = data.user;
          console.log(data);
          if (user) {
            return Promise.resolve({
              id: user.pk,
              name: user.username,
              email: user.email,
              first_name: user.first_name,
              last_name: user.last_name,
              accessToken: data.access,
              refreshToken: data.refresh,
            });
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error("Credentials are incorrect");
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I suspect that the issue may be related to how the API request is being made within the authorize function. Can someone guide me on what could be the mistake or why the request is not reaching the backend API? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: In the UI it says error localhost:3000. But the problem I am facing is its not hitting my api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error by changing localhost:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Not sure why localhost:8000 not working